# query user_tables and result is empty

Tags: oracle

I use select * from user_tables to check tables. And the result is empty. Is this because my username don't have authority to check this table or I didn't log as sysdba which I don't have authority?

Comment: Maybe your user doesn't have tables? You can try all_tables or dba_tables to see tables in other schemas, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you have not created any table yet in your schema.

`User_tables` view shows the tables which is owned by your user.

Following query shows the same result as `user_tables` view.

```
Select * from all_tables
Where owner = 'your_user';
```

Or

```
Select * from DBA_tables
Where owner = 'your_user';
```